# Javafx won't play mp3

Tags: java, javafx

I want to run mp3 without any videos with java.

```
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class Guess {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new JFXPanel();
        Media m = new Media("file:///D://Guess_the_Song//resources//new.m4a");
        MediaPlayer p = new MediaPlayer(m);
        p.play();
        
    }

}
```

This code doesn't lead me to any errors, but I can't hear any sound...

Comment: The `JFXPanel` trick only works if you call `Platform.setImplicitExit(false)` prior to creating the instance. It might be that the FXToolkit (and its native bridge used by the `MediaPlayer`), are dislose

Comment: *disposed, meaning it cannot play the sound

Comment: You also need to keep a strong reference to the `MediaPlayer` in order to avoid it being garbage collected too soon.

Comment: Is `M4A` a supported format? https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#SupportedMediaTypes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
path = "D:/Guess_the_Song/resources/new.m4a";
Media m = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
```

Comment: Still no sound :(